# Symfony PHP Unit Bridge Only Displays Deprecation Notices Once

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I've recently upgraded a Symfony app to Symfony 2.7 and at the same time I installed `symfony/phpunit-bridge`.

On the first run of `phpunit` following the installation of `symfony/phpunit-bridge` I received 821 deprecation notices after running the full test suite.

Wanting not to wait for the full test suite to run, I ran just a single test that I could see was raising a deprecation issue. I was hoping that this would run quickly and would then get me one or more deprecation notices to be getting on with fixing.

This second time I ran `phpunit` there were no deprecation notices. I thought his odd and ran `phpunit` again, both against the full test suite and against individual tests. Still no deprecation notices.

I considered that perhaps a newer version of `phpunit` would help. I was using 4.8.34 and decided to switch to ~5.0.

On the next run of `phpunit`, tada, lots of deprecation notices. Things were looking good.

On the next run of `phpunit` again, no deprecation notices.

I switched back to `phpunit` 4.8.34 and ... tada ... deprecation notices just the once.

I'm getting symfony/phpunit-bridge deprecation notices only on the first time it is run. What could be happening to cause this?

**Update**

I've since noticed that deprecation notices will be presented if the test cache is cleared before running tests.

I also noticed that the notices refer to calls to `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition::getFactoryService` and similar methods.

None of the services defined in the app use factories. This suggests a vendor is in someway doing something odd.

I can make the deprecation notices happen now at will and so will close this question.

Comment: Isn't that by intention? ... https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/phpunit_bridge.html ...

Comment: @hakre No, deprecation notices should always be shown in in relation to tests when using `symfony/phpunit-bridge`.

Comment: The issue here was that the deprecation notices were being raised when vendor services were being constructed (something that shouldn't be happenning) and that with the cache primed that didn't occur again.

Comment: That is the Symphony application building state (better known as caching [sic!]), I'd say the you need to build the application first before you run the tests (unless you test the build err the caching) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deprecation notices you see are being triggered during the container build. If the cache has already been built, it's not done so again (even in dev, though it will spend time seeing if it does need to be re-built).

Therefore, if you want to see what deprecation's exist you will need to clear the cache - or copy the output.

Note: most of the time, the deprecated code is internal to the framework, and so will be tidied up in a near-future release, it's only your own code (or libraries) that may have things that you would need to action.

#### Edit

Do this before the test execution:

```
php app/console cache:clear --no-warmup --env=test
```

Comment: Yes, I came to the same conclusion myself after a getting a little confused!

Comment: Editing to add a command line to help other users.